# Loop for indexPath swift

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have problem i don't know write loop 
Problem is with UITableView I try write condition which check for indexPath row if equal selected String

> // show error  Type 'NSIndexPath!' does not conform to protocol
>   'SequenceType'

```
 func autoCompleteTextField(_ textField: MLPAutoCompleteTextField!, didSelectAutoCompleteString selectedString: String!, withAutoCompleteObject selectedObject: MLPAutoCompletionObject!, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
       if ((selectedObject) != nil){

           print("selected object from autocomplete menu \(selectedString) with string \(selectedObject.autocompleteString())")
       }
       else {  

           for i in indexPath {
             if (indexPath.row == selectedString){
                /// to do
              }
            }       
         print("selected string \(selectedString) from autocomplete menu")
      }
 }
```

Comment: you should check values in your data source instead of indexPath.

Comment: perhaps you want something like `myArray[indexPath.row] == selectedString`